# does anybody know how to find up-to-date javadocs for google-api-java-client

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

The ones that google host seems borderline broken. For example,

http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.4.1-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/xml/atom/package-summary.html

shows examples using deprecated classes (AtomParser) and non existent methods are being called, like the addParser method call on a HttpTransport instance (I'm guessing that was supposed to be a setParser method call on a HttpRequest instance instead).

So, basically, where can I find a little bit more up to date information of this?

Comment: If google don't have proper upto date google api, I'm sorry I was laughing and forgot what I was going to type :-D

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: im on 1.10.3-beta (they are all betas or alphas as far as i can tell, might as well choose the newest one :p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to our [home page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) and click on "JavaDoc".  The latest version of the JavaDoc is linked from:

http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/index.html

Disclaimer: I am an Owner of the google-api-java-client library.

Comment: Ok, it seems the documentation is a bit out of date? In the latest javadocs, reflecting 1.10.3-beta, the examples use "new AtomParser()" which was deprecated quite a while ago (in 1.5.something), I believe its not even part of the 1.10.3-beta package. Also, it includes a call to an addParser method call of a HttpTransport instance, which doesn't seem to have such a method. Maybe time for a update? :) Thanks your work on this library, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It's in Maven Central:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/api/client/google-api-client/

Get the javadoc jar or the sources jar. Or better, use your IDE's Maven integration and it will download the sources automatically.